# How to update an xml used in a pageradapter

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-viewpager

Basically, what I'm trying to do is putting content into an XML, that is being displayed by a view pager (pager adapter). I'm trying to put content through the main activity, but I can't figure out how it would work unless I had some way to update xmls that are not the setcontentview's XML.

Answer (score 0):

For putting page content through Activty, Create a PagerAdapter to serve up your Views to the ViewPager. The key methods to implement are getCount(), instantiateItem(), destroyItem() and isViewFromObject().

http://code.google.com/p/viewpagerexample/source/browse/trunk/AwesomePager/src/com/geekyouup/paug/awesomepager/AwesomePagerActivity.java